# After running the above code why I am getting just one output for type() function ? Why not for all three?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = input("enter a name = ")
y = input("enter a integer = ")
z = input("enter a decimal number = ")    
type(x)    
type(y)    
type(z)
```

Executing the above code why I am getting just one output for `type()` function? Why not for all three?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python program that checks wether an input has an int, float or bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000035/python-program-that-checks-wether-an-input-has-an-int-float-or-bool)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add print statement to get the `type` result. And basically all of them would be `<class 'str'>` because input taken as string type.

try executing this:

```
x = input("enter a name = ")
y = input("enter a integer = ")
z = input("enter a decimal number = ")
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
print(type(z))
```

Output:

> class 'str'
>
> class 'str'
>
> class 'str'

If you need to convert the input into some other format, you need to explicitly do it, like

```
y = int(y)
z = float(z)
```

Output:

> class 'int'
>
> class 'float'

Comment: Do not forget to catch ValueError, if the user enters a wrong input